# Thunderbird updated to major new version, even on LTS

Tags: upgrade, security, thunderbird, lts

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, which is a long-term support release. I though that this was supposed to just have security fixes, not general updates.
I was therefore a bit surprised to discover that Thunderbird has been upgraded to version 115, which has a major new UI.
Was anybody else surprised by this? Surely we should just get security fixes to the earlier version of Thunderbird?

It doesn't really affect me in any significant way (yet?), but I have seen comments from others saying that various plugins have broken.

Comment: Is Thunderbird installed as a Snap like Firefox now is? If so, that might explain it. I think Snap updates are independent of the distribution updates (and I think the Snap ones update frequently).

Comment: No, I don't think Thunderbird is installed via snap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"***I thought that this was supposed to just have security fixes, not general updates.***"

There have always been a very few exceptions, including web browsers, and that opens our operatic tale of love and loss.

Since Thunderbird shares so much code with Firefox, it was included with the Firefox exception. It made sense: How could we justify version-bumping one set of code while patching a closely-related set? That would be silly.

Then, when Firefox migrated to Snap, Thunderbird's special status was revoked (it's not a web browser) and the package removed from the list of exceptions.

Folks complained loud and long that Thunderbird wasn't being updated anymore. So the Desktop Team listened and decided to keep version-bumping Thunderbird.

And you know the rest: Mozilla redesigned Thunderbird and broke some add-on compatibility. And that flowed into all releases of Ubuntu because of Thunderbird's special status.